# Why am I getting this output of first element of an array?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
    int arr[] = {},n;

    printf("Enter the number of elements you want to store in an array: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=1; i<=n;){
        printf("Enter the %dst element: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for (int i=1; i<=n;)
    {
        printf("%d",arr[i]);
        i++;
    }
    
}
```

**Output I want**

Enter the number of elements you want to store in an array: 5
Enter the 1st element: 1
Enter the 2st element: 2
Enter the 3st element: 3
Enter the 4st element: 4
Enter the 5st element: 5
Output:
12345

**Output I'm getting**
Enter the number of elements you want to store in an array: 5
Enter the 1st element: 1
Enter the 2st element: 2
Enter the 3st element: 3
Enter the 4st element: 4
Enter the 5st element: 5
Output:
**6**2345

I don't know why the first element of an array is added to the number of elements "n".

Comment: What have your learning material told you about arrays, their sizes and their indexes? Arrays in C are *not* dynamic, they have a fixed size. Also array indexes are *zero* based, which means valid indexes are from `0` to `size - 1`. Please go back to whatever resource you're using to learn the basics of C, and refresh the sections about arrays. Or possibly find some other and hopefully better learning resources.

Comment: I think you need to study up on the `for` statement as well. Your use of it is not idiomatic.

Comment: Basically: `for (int i = 1; i <= n;)` -> `for (int i = 0; i <  n; i++)` and drop the `i++` statement at the of the for loop. Also `int arr[] = {}` declares an array of size 0, so you cannot put anything into that array. You need to declare the array like this after the `scanf("%d",&n);`: `int arr[n];`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't increment `i` in any of your for loops, you just declare `i` and then provide the condition that's to be met, which leads to only the first element getting outputted. Change `for(int i=1; i<=n;)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)` which is the correct syntax because of the `i` variable getting incremented.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
    int arr[MAX], n;
    printf("Enter no of elements:- ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter elements:- \n");
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
   {
         printf("Element no %d):- ", i+1);
         scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
   }
    printf("Elements:- \n");
   for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
  {
         printf("%d ", arr[j]);     //Here space is needed after %d
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).